# Enviar un formulario cuando un input es seleccionado utilizando Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Puedo hacer que un grupo de radios envíen un formulario cuando uno de ellos es seleccionado (omitiendo así el botón de envío), así lo hago:

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

¿Pero si el formulario lo envío con `ajax`, cómo puedo lograr el mismo funcionamiento?

En `ajax` capturo el `submit` del formulario así:

```
$('#form_respuesta').on('submit', function(e){

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:  "script.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),  .... etc
```

Gracias.

Comment: Déjame ver si entiendo, la idea es obtener los valores del input sin necesidad de presionar el botón de enviar?

Comment: Sí, que el formulario se envíe con el valor del radio al seleccionar cualquiera de ellos. Sin necesidad de tener un botón de envío.

Comment: Si entiendo lo que deseas hacer entonces coloca en el atributo onchange=""  en los radios una funcion que llame al ajax, no necesitas capturar el submit ya que estas enviando los datos por AJAX,

Comment: De acuerdo. No lo había visto de ese modo, me estaba enredando innecesariamente. Ya quedó programado del modo que necesitaba. Gracias